# Integration problem ? Approach needed.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$ \int \frac{x^{-7/6}-x^{5/6}}{\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x}\sqrt[3]{x^2+x+1}}\, \mathrm{d}x $$

Its a homework question. Trigonometric substitutions make it very complex. I cannot think of any suitable method. Hints needed!

**EDIT**

Multiplying and dividing by $$x^{7/6}$$ gives :

$$ \displaystyle\int\limits^{\cssId{upper-bound-mathjax}{\class{placeholder}{}}}_{\cssId{lower-bound-mathjax}{\class{placeholder}{}}} -\dfrac{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}{\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{x}+1}-\sqrt[3]{x+\frac{1}{x}+1}}\,\cssId{int-var-mathjax}{\mathrm{d}x} $$

then its just substitution $$ x+{1/x} = t $$

Comment: looks like factoring can simplify the denominator somewhat, and factoring $x^{-7/6}$ from the numerator will leave $1-x^2$, which also looks somewhat promising. Did you try manipulating the integrand?

Comment: I think I saw it in Quora.

Comment: I also would appreciate a hint for this monster ! Is this an assignment given to you ?

Comment: This question was given as a practice question for upcoming exams.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It seems pretty easy now :v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int \frac{x^{-7/6}-x^{5/6}}{\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x}\sqrt[3]{x^2+x+1}}\, \mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\int \frac{x^{-7/6}(1-x^2)}{\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt{x}\sqrt{(x+\frac1x)+1}-\sqrt{x}\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt[3]{(x+\frac1x)+1}}\, \mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\int -\frac{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}{\sqrt{(x+\frac1x)+1}-\sqrt[3]{(x+\frac1x)+1}}\, \mathrm{d}x$$
now let $x+\dfrac1x=u^6$ then
$$I=\int-\dfrac{6u^5}{u^3-u^2}\ du$$

Comment: Yeah! Thanks @Nosrati

Comment: you are welcome. If you find the answer, you can delete the question!

Comment: @IceOwl Don't delete the question. This could be useful for other people who have a similar question.